# Bootstrap vertical alignment not working no matter what

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've read tons of different topics and articles about that common issue but still no working solution. Now I'm kinda desperate so I'd very grateful for any help and here's code:

```css
.auth-tab {
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
   <div class="auth-tab col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-5 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
    sth
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

What I want is to vertically and horizontally align `.auth-tab`

Answer (score -1):

Break it down into small testable steps without referencing all the various classes at once. Start with just the container, row and single column. Then test to evaluate if it works. Then add one more class and test. Repeat until you see what fails. My guess is the syntax. What version of bootstrap is being used. Also, instead of calling a bootstrap class, call the css attribute; style=“text-align:center;”.

Comment: I might try and add text-align:center; to the auth-tab attribute to see if it works.

Comment: i dont need the text to be aligned, the whole div is required. version - 4.1.3

Comment: @run4w4y did you try my suggestion?

Comment: yep, just pure `.container` and `.row align-items-center` but still nothing